# Custom table caption (Updated)

Tags: tables, captions, line-breaking, indentation

I'd like to achieve a custom table (figure) format with Table numbering and title (this is usually the title also used in the list of tables but does not have to be) in boldface, and the (longer) description below the title formatted like a paragraph, that means first line indented and next lines not. I have read the `caption` manual but there is no direct solution. Short Illustration:

**Table 1: Title** (numbering + title)

description formatted like a paragraph (second line to end, with first line indented, rest not)

And here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, smallheadings,]{scrreprt}
\overfullrule=1mm
\DeclareRobustCommand{\captionpar}{\par}
\usepackage[labelfont={small,bf}, textfont=small, labelsep=colon,singlelinecheck=false,format=plain, parindent=1em]{caption}
\newlength\myindention
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}%
{#1#2\\\hspace*{\myindention}#3}
\setlength\myindention{1em}
\captionsetup{format=myformat}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table description description description description description    description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description }
\centering
\fbox{Inhalt der Tabelle}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the title in boldface is missing in the current format. Is there any way to add this separated from the rest of the describing text? Thanks.

Comment: I get the expected output from this setup: »**Table 0.1:**« and then in the next line the indented paragraph...

Comment: @cgnieder It's close but not exact. The Title is missing next to the numbering 'Table 0.1'. The description looks fine the way it is.

Comment: Which title are you speaking of? Both the caption label and the caption text are there!

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood... Are you asking how to define such a title feature?

Comment: @cgnieder I refer to a custom table title, for example the one used for the list of tables, but it could also be a different one. For example: Table 1: The development of unemployment in the United States. Then the (longer) description follows. Edit: yes that's what I meant. I want to add titles to all my tables and figures, which are formatted differently from the descriptions - that means in boldface, and without indentation.

Comment: In the list of tables the caption text `<text>` from \caption{<text>}` is used or, if given, the input `<short>` from the optional argument: `\caption[<short>]{<long>}`. Per default there is no such thing as a table title...

Comment: @cgnieder Yes. The background is the following: I have used `\caption[short]` for all my tables, so they show up in the list of tables. But now my advisor is telling me that he also wants these (or other custom) table titles as part of each table in the document, before the longer descriptions. So I need to add these titles somehow.

Comment: edit: Here I found something similar, it's close to what I want to achieve I think: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97278/using-a-caption-label-as-a-title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly from the comments you can adapt the solution from the question ([Using a caption label as a title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97278)) you linked to.

In this example I only used `[h]` as float specifier so I can easily copy and paste the result:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, smallheadings,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[
  labelfont={small,bf},
  textfont={small},
  labelsep=colon,singlelinecheck=false,format=plain,
  parindent=1em]{caption}

\newcommand\thistablecaption{}
\newcommand{\tablecaption}[2]{\def\thistablecaption{#1}\caption[#1]{#2}}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{%
  #1#2{\captionlabelfont\thistablecaption}\par#3%
}

\captionsetup{format=myformat}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}[h]
  \tablecaption{Title of this table}{A table description description description
    description description description description description description
    description description description description description description
    description description description description description description }
  \centering
  \fbox{Inhalt der Tabelle}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Another table}
  Another one without title
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you! It does the job if every table has a title. (As you can see the second doesn't, so a colon looks kind of weird there, but I need to give a title to every single table anyways) The only things which could be improved are: - to stick with the original `caption` as in the 2nd solution of the linked thread, so I don't have to change the format or rewrite all the brackets for every single table; - provide a solution which can be applied to figures as well, or separately.